# scrapy ERROR: Spider error processing issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm very new to scrapy, while am running my code, am getting this error.

My Code

```
import urlparse

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
class legco(BaseSpider):
name = "sec_gov"

allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov", "search.usa.gov", "secsearch.sec.gov"]
start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany"]

#extract home page search results
def parse(self, response):
for link in response.xpath('//div[@id="seriesDiv"]//table[@class="tableFile2"]/a/@href').extract():
    req = Request(url = link, callback = self.parse_page)
    print link
    yield req

#extract second link search results
def parse_second(self, response):
for link in response.xpath('//div[@id="seriesDiv"]//table[@class="tableFile2"]//*[@id="documentsbutton"]/a/@href').extract():
    req = Request(url = link, callback = self.parse_page)
    print link
    yield req
```

Once I tried to run this code : **scrapy crawl sec_gov** am getting this error.

```
2018-11-14 15:37:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-14 15:37:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-14 15:37:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-11-14 15:37:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany> (referer: None)
2018-11-14 15:37:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/surukam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/home/surukam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in parse
raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: legco.parse callback is not defined
2018-11-14 15:37:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: this is python 2 code?

Comment: Thanks for your response dejan, Yes it was python 2 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should not run at all. There are several things to fix in order for your script to run. Where have you found this `self.parse_page` and what is it doing within your script? Your script is badly indented. I've fixed the script which is now able to track each url from it's landing page connected to concerning links to the documentation in it's inner page. Try this to get the content.

```
import scrapy

class legco(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sec_gov"

    start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href').extract():
            absoluteLink = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = absoluteLink, callback = self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//a[@id="documentsbutton"]/@href').extract():
            targetLink = response.urljoin(links)
            yield {"links":targetLink}
```

Comment: Check out the script @Vinod kumar to get the links to the various documentations.

Comment: Oh great, it was working, My goal is : There atre more files but  TO DOWNLOAD THE SPECIFIC TYPE FILE (example : EX-10.1, EX-10.2, ....Ex-10.99) **path :** BaseUrl-> CIK links -> Documents-> download files. (Ex-10 Files) files are available in .htm and .txt .

Comment: Stop asking multdimensional questions all at once. If it serves the purpose of your initial requirement, try asking another question describing your further attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Am sorry, am new to scrapy, If you can help me with this?

Comment: I have to download the specific Type contracts, so what changes i have to do ? Can you help me with this pls,

Comment: Hello SIM, Its not entering into next page.., What chnages I have to do to go to next page.

Comment: Ask a new question about your requirement. I hope somebody will surely take a look. Thanks.